# .htaccess file not working on php website

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
http://www.example.com/questions.php?scid=6
```

I want to make this url as:

```
http://www.example.com/general-knowledge_questions-answers_indian-constitution-1
```

what code i have to use in my .htaccess file

Comment: There appears to be no direct translation possible between the original and how you would like it to look. The original uses `scid` which is an integer but your desired output uses a string not mentioned in the original

Answer (score 0):

Use redirect code in `.htacess`

```
//301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 http://www.example.com/questions.php?scid=6 http://www.example.com/general-knowledge_questions-answers_indian-constitution-1
```